# How to validate errors in Backbone.Form field:blur event?

Tags: backbone.js

I want to validate some form field in blur event. How can i do it with [Backbone.Form](https://github.com/powmedia/backbone-forms.git)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this:

```
form.on('password:blur', function() { 
    form.fields.password.validate();
});
```

Comment: Thank you. But this path will lead to a lot of repetition of code. А project has many fields that require checks on blur event, change event. (For example, requests for access to login to the server, check the password strength) on that I prefer it to create their own editors.

Comment: I understand your concept you had 3 scope.
Form scope-responsible for the entire shape of the whole.
Field scope-responsible for the input, label, and helpers
Editor scope-responsible for the input, processing the data in the editor.
Maybe it would be better to me implement event subscription Field-> Editor and then already engaged in the handling of events in the Field?
But then how to create different from other fields? This requires the addition to the  model.schema? It draws on the pull request. Is there a need for such a feature?

Comment: Yep it's something I think we need to update, so the event callback would receive `field` instead of `form, editor`

Answer (score 2):

I found it. May be useful to someone else.

```
var oldText= Backbone.Form.editors.Text;
var newText= oldText.extend({
    initialize: function(options) {
        oldText.prototype.initialize.call(this,options);
        this.on("blur",function(){
            this.form.fields[this.options.key].validate();
        });
    }         
});
Backbone.Form.editors.Text=newText;
```

This code change basic text editor and all input[type="text"] and  other extends fields will validate on blur event.

If you  want create one "blur validate field".  You can create new editor.

```
Backbone.Form.editors.BlurText=  Backbone.Form.editors.Text.extend({
    initialize: function(options) {
        Backbone.Form.editors.Text.prototype.initialize.call(this,options);
        this.on("blur",function(){
            this.form.fields[this.options.key].validate();
        });
    }         
});
```

Now you can use it in schema:

```
var User = Backbone.Model.extend({
    schema: { 
        username: {
            type:'BlurText',
            validators: ['required']
        }
    }
});
```