# Backbone.js and form input blur

Tags: forms, events, backbone.js, textbox, blur

I am pretty much a backbonejs newbie.   I am submitting form data to mysql.

I have one special input box where the use types in his or her email address as a user name. 
As it stands, I can check all my input fields (user, pass, address, phone, etc) client
side, use an event on a button, load the model, use PHP to put the data into the db.
This works just fine and is tested.  The backend validation works fine and feeds to
the browser when necessary.

Now I want to check the loginname field against the back end BEFORE writing the record (I know I can trap this on the back end in the final submit but want to do it here).  If the user already has an account with the same email address I want to catch that client side. The issue is I can't seem to find a way to capture this blur (or onblur or change whatever I use) when I move off the loginname field so I can (in the render of the view is all I can figure) go off, use PHP again and send back a flag "new" or "existing"

No errors in Google developer tool

```
    define([
   'jquery',
   'underscore',
   'backbone',
   'lib/jquery-migrate-1.2.1',
   'models/RegisterModel',
   'text!templates/RegisterTemplate.html',
   'lib/jquery.maskedinput-1.0',
   'lib/bootstrap-acknowledgeinput.min',
   'lib/jqBootstrapValidation'
    ], function($, _, Backbone, jQueryMigrate, RegisterModel, RegisterTemplate,   
        MaskedInput,Ack, jqAck){

   var RegisterView = Backbone.View.extend({

    el: $("#container"),
    events: {
          'click .btn-primary': 'saveClient',
          'focusout .loginname': 'usercheck'
       },

     usercheck: function() {     //** not working
         console.log("usercheck detected");
         alert("Alerts suck.");
         },

     render: function(){

    //Since our template has dynamic variables in it, we need to compile it
    var compiledTemplate = _.template( RegisterTemplate, this.model );
    this.$el.html(compiledTemplate); //Replaces EVERYTHING inside the <div 
                                           id="container">
    this.$('#phone').mask('(999) 999-9999');
        this.$('#phone2').mask('(999) 999-9999');
    this.$('#zip').mask('99999');

        $(function () {     //**  working
           $("input,select,textarea").not("[type=submit]").jqBootstrapValidation(); 
         });

    $('.loginname').live("click", function () {    //** not working
       alert('AHHHHHH!');
     });

        $().acknowledgeinput({        // ** this works fine
            success_color: '#00FF00',
        danger_color: '#FF0000',
         update_on: 'keyup'
        });
```

****  I looked in Chrome at the blur event for the input with name/id  = loginname

HTML I did look at the blur for the elmement with id (Chrome says it's input#loginname)
does have the blur event attached to it.  I changed my code a bit, but still it doesn't seem to trigger. I never know with backbone if it's just something simple or one of those
"this and scope" issues     :)

```
<div id="container" class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span6">
    <div class="requiredNotice"><i class="icon-warning-sign icon-red"></i>&nbsp;Can't    
             be blank!</div>
    <h3>New Client Registration:</h3>
   <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST">
       <fieldset>
           <div class="control-group">
     <label class="control-label required" for="loginname">UserID (Email
             </label>
       <div class="controls">
                  <div class="input-prepend" data-role="acknowledge-input">
          <div data-role="acknowledgement"><i></i></div>
                         <input type="email" data-type="email" required="required"    
                             placeholder="Use email account"
                 maxlength="254" name="loginname" id="loginname" 
                             class="inputclass pageRequired
                 input-xlarge" />
            </div>
         <span class="loginname_error label label-info hide"></span>
       </div>
      </div>    ... etc

 events: {
         'click .btn-primary'   : 'saveClient',
         'focusout #input.loginname' : 'userCheck'      
      //   "blur input.loginname"      : "userCheck"
    },


 userCheck: function(e) {
     console.log("usercheck detected");
     alert("Alerts suck.");     
   },
```

Comment: Try binding the event directly in the initialize event instead of using the events hash.

Comment: Can you provide the sample code?  If you have defined an $el, bind means append to the currently defined $el, right?  I don't have an initialize func in this view per se, just events { }

Comment: If you are still interested on  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13437822/how-to-validate-errors-in-backbone-form-fieldblur-event I can help tomorrow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.live` is not needed here, there is nothing wrong with your event hash as well. There could be some thing wrong with template. I did just isolate the input field and `focusout` event in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ravikumaranantha/fgqNJ/1/) it's working fine.

```
<script type="text/template" id="formtemplate">    
    <form>
        <input type="text" class="loginname"  value="" placeholder="enter login"/>
    </form>
</script>
```

...

```
var View = Backbone.View.extend({
    events:{
        'focusout .loginname':'checkUser'
    },
    render:function(){
        this.$el.html($('#formtemplate').html());
    },
    checkUser:function(e){
        alert('checkUser'); //works well
    }
});

var view = new View();
view.render();
view.$el.appendTo('body');
```

Comment: Thanks for looking.  Still doesn't work.  I don't seem to be able to put a break point on the event line, and the code never reaches the checkUser function.

Comment: inspect `.loginname` in chrome developer tools, and check in event listeners tab, it should have a `blur` event associated with that. If not some thing wrong with your template/selectors

Answer (score 0):

Okay - you said to tie this to blur, and this format finally worked!

'blur input#loginname'      : 'userCheck'

```
events: {
         'click .btn-primary'   : 'saveClient',    
         'blur input#loginname'      : 'userCheck'
      },
userCheck: function(e) {

     console.log("usercheck detected");
     alert("Alerts suck.");

  },
```

The console is not showing up, but at least I'm trapping the blur now!   Thanks eveyone.